# Python: slice: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a module that searches for a key string in a target string and outputs the starting points of any matches. I can write an iterative module that achieves this, but I'm attempting to do it with recursion (the tutorial I'm using deals with recursion and iteration in this lesson, so I figure I should try both) and running into some trouble.

```
def substringmatchrecursive(target, key):
"""returns a tuple of the starting points of matches of the key string in the target string using a recursive function"""
from string import find
position = find(target, key) #position of the match
answer=() #will be outputted 
if position == -1:
    return 'No match'
else:
    while position != 1:
        answer = answer + (position, )
        position = substringmatchrecursive(target[position+1: ], key)
return answer
```

loading the module and entering

```
substringmatchrecursive("fjdkakfjdslkfajfksja", "a")
```

which should give me a tuple of length 3, instead gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
position = substringmatchrecursive(target[position+1: ], key)

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I'd assume that `find()` would output an integer, so `position+1` should work. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to following code, `substringmatchrecursive` returns `str` object (`'No match'`) if it does not find a key.

```
if position == -1:
    return 'No match'
```

And that `str` object is assigned to `position`:

```
position = substringmatchrecursive(target[position+1: ], key)
```

---

Make the function return **a tuple** consistently. (a predicate used in the `while` loop should be adjusted accordingly, or `while` should be gone if you want recursion, ...).

And use different name for `position` to avoid name collision.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.

Why shouldn't I use a while loop in recursion?

And what do you mean when you talk about name collision? I can't see where I've assigned 'position' to two different things.

Comment: @user3106040, `position = find(target, key)` <-- `int`,  `position = substringmatchrecursive(target[position+1: ], key)` <-- `tuple` or `string`.

Comment: @user3106040, You can use while loop. But it will involves unnecessary duplicated operations.

Comment: user3106040: Don't [just] thank @falsetru, accept his answer.